# serving GWT permutations from appengine blob store - XSRF not found

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc

In trying to serve GWT permutations out of the blob store in order to escape the AppEngine hard limit of 150 mb for static files, I've succeed in doing so for "html" and image files "jpeg, png, .etc" and other .rpc calls, but am hung up on XSRF calls.

In the server logs, I see:
The serialization policy file '/theapplication/CCA65B31464BDB27545C23C142FEEEF8.gwt.rpc' was not found;

My upload log shows it was uploaded /CCA65B31464BDB27545C23C142FEEEF8.gwt.rpc : HTTP/1.1 200 OK

The request url shows http://14.applicationXYZ.appspot.com/xsrf

the RequestPayload shows: http://14.applicationXYZ.appspot.com/theapplication/|CCA65B31464BDB27545C23C142FEEEF8|com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.XsrfTokenService|getNewXsrfToken|1|2|3|4|0|

Other rpc calls are resolving (via a server filter is looking for /theapplication and mapping the requests to a blob to serve) as in the following case where an rpc call is made without an Xsrf request (as the user is not logged in yet)

req url -- http://14.applicationXYZ.appspot.com/someRPCCall

RequestPayload -- http://14.applicationXYZ.appspot.com/theapplication/|62D7E6737056C685E10947B640409549|com.abc.client.rpc.Service|doWork|java.lang.String/2004016611|java.lang.Boolean/476441737|wwwerr|1|2|3|4|3|5|5|6|7|7|6|0|

So, I have two questions:

1) why is XSRF call failing to return the appropriate blob, ie. why doesn't the xrsf call get handled by the filter the way other url calls to /theapplication/* do?
2) What can I do about it?
3) Also, I tried setting the content type to "text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8 and also as unspecified when I uploaded the blob.  Anyone know what the content type should be for *.gwt.rpc in case I do get the xrsf working?  Could having the wrong content type be causing the trouble?

***note applicationXYZ is not the real name so no the links won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK /xsrf is mapped to a servlet as well, so if the filter returns a blob without passing on the filter, it seems it won't reach the servlet.

Anyway, it's easy enough just to upload the few .rpc files as normal and not serve them as blobs.